# How do I type the Spanish inverted question mark in Emacs?

Tags: windows, emacs, language, spanish

I want to write in Spanish without having to keep Charmap open! How do I type the Spanish inverted question and exclamation marks?

*¡Quiero escribir en Castellano sin usar el charmap! ¿Cómo escribo los signos de interrogación y exclamación?*

- How do I type these characters in Emacs?
- How do I type them in any general input box in Windows?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answering our own questions is encouraged, so here we go:

### In any Windows editor or text box

Source: [here](https://www.fileformat.info/tip/microsoft/enter_unicode.htm)

Hold Alt and type a number corresponding to the char code.

To use the decimal Unicode value, prefix the number with a zero, example: Alt 0191

To use the decimal windows code page value, prefix the number with a zero, example: Alt 161

According to source, you can also type the Unicode hex value, but that needs an entry in registry and did not work for me.

- Inverted question mark (¿):
- Alt 0191
- Alt 168
- Alt +00A1
- Inverted exclamation mark (­¡):
- Alt 0161
- Alt 173
- Alt +00BF

### In Emacs

Source: [xahlee's Emacs page](http://xahlee.info/emacs/emacs/emacs_n_unicode.html).

1. Inverted question mark (¿):

- C-x 8 ?

2. Inverted exclamation mark (­¡):

- C-x 8 !

You can also use function ucs-insert (`M-x ucs-insert` or `C-x 8 RET`) and Emacs will request a hex value to insert the character.

Or set the input method (`M-x set-input-method`) to ucs and type normally. To insert a Unicode char, type `u`.

Comment: Looks comprehensive to me, have +1. Mine was a bit brief as I was on the way out of the office and thought it would be better than nothing, hope it helped!

Comment: It did! Thanks for your time and for linking to the website. Many thanks !

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/bf/index.htm) you can type the ¿ character by holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> and typing <kbd>1</kbd>,<kbd>6</kbd>,<kbd>8</kbd> on the number pad (make sure num lock is on).

This works on a standard UK keyboard on Windows XP running setup as English UK, as that's how I've written the ¿ character both times in this post, and I think should work on other setups as it's the standard entry method for unicode characters.

There might be a faster way if you have a Spanish keyboard and/or language settings, but I don't have any experience of that to be able to comment.

And, unfortunate, I cannot help with how you type the character in to emacs.

Comment: What about the exclamation marks ?

Comment: Alt 173 (Follow link. Enter 'INVERTED EXCLAMATION MARK' in searchbox.)

Answer (score 0):

For an Emacs solution, use one of its [input methods](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Input-Methods.html). For the characters used in Spanish, another possibility is [`iso-transl`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Unibyte-Mode.html), which lets you type `C-x 8 ?` for `¿`, `C-x 8 ' a` for `á`, etc.

For an OS solution, you could remap your keyboard to make the characters available through <kbd>AltGr</kbd>, dead keys or a <kbd>Compose</kbd> key. Windows is a bit lacking here, and in particular doesn't support Compose out of the box. I use [AllChars](http://sourceforge.net/projects/allchars/); note that you need Emacs 24 (e.g. downloaded from the [EmacsW32 site](http://ourcomments.org/cgi-bin/emacsw32-dl-latest.pl)) as the current stable version doesn't recognize AllChars's “fake” keypresses.

Answer (score 0):

**Emacs**

(The following solution is really for writing in Spanish.  If just a
¿ is to be inserted once or twice in your document then the other answers might be more appropriate)

A convenient way to write Spanish in Emacs with an American QWERTY keyboard is to use the input methods `spanish-prefix` or `spanish-postfix` (for a general introduction into input methods see [Emacs User Manual - Sect. 22.3](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Input-Methods.html) - this is very convenient framework if you have to edit/compose text in several languages).

For `spanish-postfix` the following key combinations enable to write the diacritics and special characters of the Spanish language:

```
KEY SEQUENCE
------------
You can input characters by the following key sequences:
key char  [type a key sequence to insert the corresponding character]
--- ---- --- ---- --- ---- --- ---- --- ---- --- ---- --- ----
!/  ¡    A'  Á    I'  Í    O'  Ó    a'  á    i'  í    o'  ó
?/  ¿    E'  É    N~  Ñ    U'  Ú    e'  é    n~  ñ    u'  ú

Doubling the postfix separates the letter and postfix:
a'' -> a'   n~~ -> n~, etc.

key character(s)  [type a key (sequence) and select one from the list]
--- ------------
U"  Ü U"
u"  ü U"
```

For `spanish-prefix` it works like this:

```
    effect   | prefix | examples
 ------------+--------+----------
    acute    |   '    | 'a -> á
  diaeresis  |   "    | "u -> ü
    tilde    |   ~    | ~n -> ñ
   symbol    |   ~    | ~> -> »   ~< -> «   ~! -> ¡   ~? -> ¿
```

Above tables are excerpts from the information you get by doing `M-x describe-input-method` on the respective input methods.

In order to activate the input-mode you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> and enter `spanish-postfix` or `spanish-prefix`.  Now the key-combinations are activated, e.g. pressing <kbd>~</kbd><kbd>?</kbd> (`spanish-prefix`) or <kbd>?</kbd><kbd>/</kbd> (`spanish-postfix`) produces the desired ¿.

If you are done with writing non-QWERTY characters, you can switch back to the normal input method by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>.

**Windows > 8**

One way is to switch the global input method back and forth between your default keyboard layout and a Spanish keyboard layout.  For a detailed HowTo see here: https://kb.wisc.edu/helpdesk/page.php?id=27310